# need to call client side javascript from vb.net or vice versa or write to DOM from vb.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vb.net, tablesorter

I have a web application that utilizes javascript, jquery, and vb.net. I have a button that, when clicked, causes a jquery click function to be called. It sets a few variables (based on user inputs) and then calls a javascript function that calls a server side Pagemethod (which calls a DLL to do the calculations, etc.) The results come back and I use Tablesorter to display the results. This worked very well until the need arose for the drop down controls on the page to be bound to values in a table.

Of course, the drop downs are bound in the server side code in the Page_Init Sub. That also means, however, that I cannot access the selected items in those dropdowns from the client side javascript/jquery (or can I?).

I have the controls defined on the server side (Protected WithEvents) and am able to bind and refer to them on the server side...outside of the Pagemethod, that is. Since it has to be declared as Public Shared, it won't allow me to reference the page controls since they are not explicitly defined in that Pagemethod.

I thought I would just rewrite the jquery click event on the server side, but that presents me the problem of getting the results back to the client side to be rendered by Tablesorter.

If there was another (or better) way to call the server side code from javascript so I wouldn't have to use a Pagemethod, that would conceivably work also.

I also kicked around the idea of writing the table html from the server side code and then Tablesorter would be able to render it, but I haven't found a good way yet.

To potentially complicate the issue, I'm using master pages. The main master page contains the jquery and javascript code, the other master page applies to a subgroup of pages in my app (including the page I'm working with now) and is where the button in question actually resides.

I've tried the "<%= %>" method, but I cannot get the code to recognize the variable.

I can post code, if needed, but my question is more general in nature regarding methodology, rather than a specific syntax for my scenario.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issues I was having using Client Callbacks as described in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). It was exactly what I needed, however, I did have to pass in a concatenated variable. I needed two variables to check for certain conditions and the Callback only accepts one.